# Is there a way to select Pivot table rows and columns based on a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a Pivot Table based on column headings selected from a combobox in a userform.

```
ComboBox1.List = Sheets("ListTable").Range("A1:A10").Value
```

then store on a worksheet.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Input"
    Range("A1") = ComboBox1.Value
```

Now I want to select the columns (and rows) for the pivot as **A1 on "Input"** Sheet.

Thus:

```vb
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields(**"INPUT OF A1"**)
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1 
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields( _
                      Worksheets("Input").Range("A1").Value)
```